# How do you get multiple saves?

Tags: prison-architect

In Prison Architect how do you get multiple saves? I can only have one autosave at a time, and if I make a new account it gets deleted!

Answer (score 3):

Games can be saved and loaded from the pause menu (<kbd>Esc</kbd>), allowing you to have multiple prisons on the go.  However there is only one autosave slot, meaning you must be careful to save your prison manually before loading a new game.  Otherwise, your changes will be overwritten.